# mautic - I want to add contact in mautic via api

Tags: api, mautic

I want to add contact in mautic via an API. Below I have the code, but it's not adding the contact in mautic.

I have installed mautic in localhost. Studied the API form in the mautic documentation and tried to do it for at least 2 days, but I am not getting any results on it.

```php
<?php

                // Bootup the Composer autoloader
                include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';  

                use Mautic\Auth\ApiAuth;

                session_start();

                $publicKey = '';
                $secretKey = '';
                $callback  = '';

                // ApiAuth->newAuth() will accept an array of Auth settings
                $settings = array(
                    'baseUrl'          => 'http://localhost/mautic',       // Base URL of the Mautic instance
                    'version'          => 'OAuth2', // Version of the OAuth can be OAuth2 or OAuth1a. OAuth2 is the default value.
                    'clientKey'        => '1_1w6nrty8k9og0kow48w8w4kww8wco0wcgswoow80ogkoo0gsks',       // Client/Consumer key from Mautic
                    'clientSecret'     => 'id6dow060fswcswgsgswgo4c88cw0kck4k4cc0wkg4gows08c',       // Client/Consumer secret key from Mautic
                    'callback'         => 'http://localhost/mtest/process.php'        // Redirect URI/Callback URI for this script
                );

                /*
                // If you already have the access token, et al, pass them in as well to prevent the need for reauthorization
                $settings['accessToken']        = $accessToken;
                $settings['accessTokenSecret']  = $accessTokenSecret; //for OAuth1.0a
                $settings['accessTokenExpires'] = $accessTokenExpires; //UNIX timestamp
                $settings['refreshToken']       = $refreshToken;
                */

                // Initiate the auth object
                $initAuth = new ApiAuth();
                $auth = $initAuth->newAuth($settings);
                /*
                if( $auth->getAccessTokenData() != null ) {
                        $accessTokenData = $auth->getAccessTokenData();
                        $settings['accessToken']        = $accessTokenData['access_token'];
                        $settings['accessTokenSecret']  = 'id6dow060fswcswgsgswgo4c88cw0kck4k4cc0wkg4gows08c'; //for OAuth1.0a
                        $settings['accessTokenExpires'] = $accessTokenData['expires']; //UNIX timestamp
                        $settings['refreshToken']       = $accessTokenData['refresh_token'];
                }*/
                // Initiate process for obtaining an access token; this will redirect the user to the $authorizationUrl and/or
                // set the access_tokens when the user is redirected back after granting authorization

                // If the access token is expired, and a refresh token is set above, then a new access token will be requested

                try {
                    if ($auth->validateAccessToken()) {

                        // Obtain the access token returned; call accessTokenUpdated() to catch if the token was updated via a
                        // refresh token

                        // $accessTokenData will have the following keys:
                        // For OAuth1.0a: access_token, access_token_secret, expires
                        // For OAuth2: access_token, expires, token_type, refresh_token

                        if ($auth->accessTokenUpdated()) {
                            $accessTokenData = $auth->getAccessTokenData();
                            echo "<pre>";
                            print_r($accessTokenData);
                            echo "</pre>";
                            //store access token data however you want
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    // Do Error handling
                }






                use Mautic\MauticApi;
                //use Mautic\Auth\ApiAuth;

                // ...
                $initAuth   = new ApiAuth();
                $auth       = $initAuth->newAuth($settings);
                $apiUrl     = "http://localhost/mautic/api";
                $api        = new MauticApi();
                $contactApi = $api->newApi("contacts", $auth, $apiUrl); 

                $data = array(
                    'firstname' => 'Jim',
                    'lastname'  => 'Contact',
                    'email'     => 'jim@his-site.com',
                    'ipAddress' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
                );

                $contact = $contactApi->create($data);
                echo "<br/>contact created";
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you remove the try/catch and see if you get any errors logged to help debugging?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting ? can you please provide some errors either from your api resposne or from mautic logs ?

Answer (score 4):

```php
   use Curl\Curl;
    
    $curl = new Curl();
    
    $un = 'mayank';
    $pw = 'mayank';
    $hash = base64_encode($un.':'.$pw);
    
    $curl->setHeader('Authorization','Basic '.$hash);
    $res = $curl->post(
        'http://mautic.local/api/contacts/new',
        [
            'firstname'=>'fn',
            'lastname'=>'ln',
            'email'=>'t1@test.com'
        ]
    );
    
    var_dump($res);
```

This is something very simple i tried and it worked for me, please try cleaning cache and enable logging, unless you provide us some error it's hard to point you in right direction. Please check for logs in app/logs directory as well as in /var/logs/apache2 directory.

Comment: please explain with 0 level

Comment: @ErSahajArora I am not sure what is 0 level, its very simple api code, if you are working with php, i have used php curl api library here, you can find easily on github. Further, just write it in any file in your php code where you can execute it and you should be able to make the call.

Comment: i got the error 
Uncaught Error: Class 'Curl\Curl' not found.
please solve

Comment: Call to undefined method Curl::setHeader()  
solve curl/curl now got header error

Comment: @ErSahajArora https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class use this

Answer (score 3):

In my experience sometimes after activating the API in the settings the API only starts working after clearing the cache.

1. Make sure you have activated the API in the settings
2. Clear the cache:

   `cd /path/to/mautic`
   `rm -rf app/cache/*`
3. Then try again
4. If this didn't work, try to use the BasicAuth example (You have to enable this I the settings again and add a new User to set the credentials)

I suspect that the OAuth flow might be disturbed by the local settings / SSL configuration.

Comment: SSL may be the problem as OAuth2 requires https.

Answer (score 0):

these steps may be useful:

- make sure API is enabled(yes I know it's might be obvious but still);
- check the logs;
- check the response body;
- try to send it as simple json via Postman

it may be one of the following problems:

- Cache;
- You are not sending the key:value; of the required custom field;
- you are mistaken with authentication;

  Good luck :)